# Zookeeper not starting in localhost

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and I had downloaded Apache-zookeeper-3.4.6 and set the zoo.cfg as per documentation. I started the zookeeper server it starts and when I checked the status of the server and it returns

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config:/home/bigdata/zookeeper/bin..conf/zoo.cfg
Mode:standalone
```

but when I opened

```
   localhost:2181
```

in browser, it says no data received...

Anybody help me...

Answer (score -1):

After starting zookeeper ,It will not render in any browser.U need to write a sample client or you can use zoo-inspector (Open source UI given by Apache) to connect to this .

Comment: ...can u tell me how to do it with zoo-inspector...@Sandeep Das

Comment: You can follow https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/zookeeper/trunk/src/contrib/zooinspector/README.txt to build and run zooInspector

Comment: thank you...@Sandeep Das...can you suggest me a website where I can learn about zookeeper internally...

Comment: Best source I have found is "2009-Book-Hadoop the Definitive Guide".....You can download PDF . There is one whole chapter about Zookeeper .For further readings you can refer Apache site

Comment: once again thank u...@Sandeep Das....I cant get some concepts...can you tell me the difference between client and server in zookeeper ...

Comment: when you run "zkServer.cmd" ...Zookeper server runs ...The application which uses this server is the client .For eg-Hadoop ,Kafka ,Storm uses zookeeper .Here we can call Hadoop ,Kafka and Storm are clients for zookeeper. ZooInspector is also a client of zookeeper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58740/discussion-between-user3797438-and-sandeep-das).